# $scope variable not updating between controllers - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a header view as

```
<div ng-controller="navCtrl">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-show="isAuthenticated">
      <li> <a ui-sref="logout"> Logout </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The navigation controller

```
(function(){
    var navigationController = function($scope, authToken){
        $scope.isAuthenticated = authToken.isAuthenticated(); //return bool
    };
    navigationController.$inject = ['$scope','authToken'];
    angular.module('simpleApp')
        .controller('navCtrl', navigationController);
}());
```

I have another logout controller

```
(function(){
    var logoutController = function($scope ,authToken, $state){
        $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
        $state.go('main');
    };
    logoutController.$inject = ['$scope', 'authToken', '$state'];
    angular.module('simpleApp')
        .controller('logoutCtrl', logoutController);
}());
```

When I click on the Logout link i set `$scope.isAuthenticated = false;` , expecting the navigation menu to hide but it dosent.

Something seems to be done in the wrong way :(

[Link to Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uz9Dyz?p=preview)

Comment: your page has 3 different angular modules, each with their own `$scope`.  how would you expect changing a property on one of them to affect the other two?

Comment: same name for module across the controllers won't help ?

Comment: @Claies in the plunkr they are all using the same module

Comment: @epynic where's the logout button in your plunkr?

Comment: @Katana24 exactly thats the problem , then i submit the login the form i set  `$scope.isAuthenticated = true;` expecting the view navigation to show up  `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-show="isAuthenticated">`

Comment: Just started to learn angular :)

Comment: a new `$scope` is created any time that an element has an `ng-controller` attached.  unless they are nested (and they are not, in your case), each element group (i.e. from `<div>` to `</div>`) are *separate*.  in other words, you cannot change a `$scope` property in one controller and see the effect of that change in another.  You need to use Services or events to share data between controllers.

Comment: updated plunk with a factory http://plnkr.co/edit/uz9Dyz ,i am afraid somethings still wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are glued to DOM elements, and possibly to each other. They are not singletons and they are not connected to modules (they serve as the model layer, not as the service layer).

Since scopes can form a hierarchy, based on the DOM tree, you could keep the common data in the topmost scope; this way it would be reachable from any descendant scope.

Comment: sorry, I am still confused in logout controller `$scope.isAuthenticated` is set to `false;` that should update the `ng-show="isAuthenticated"` right  , as Scopes are glue to each other?

Comment: Scopes are glued to each other when they are nested. Then the inner scopes can see attributes from their outer scopes. You are trying to see an attribute from an inner scope (login) in the outer scope (navigation), which will not work. As stated in my answer, keep the data in your topmost scope. Or in this case, the real solution is to add a login service object.

Comment: can you have a look at the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/uz9Dyz ,have created a factory and i am stuck now

Answer (score 1):

Change $scope to $rootScope in both controllers than it will work. $rootScope is the topmost scope.

Just for the record: this is not my preferred solution, I would go with a service.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uz9Dyz , can you check that updated plunk pls . created a factory ,how can i make the controllers to talk to each other ?